# Ruby equivalent to Python's "array[i:]" to select all array elements after i?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I find myself wanting something like Python's

```
ary = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
ary[2:] #=> [3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

ALL of the time these days.

The solution always ends up being multi-lined and ugly. I'm wondering what the most elegant solutions out there might be, because mine are not worth showing.

Comment: It's not much different: `ary[2..-1]`.

Comment: The `-1` in a Range is somewhat ugly and magic when used in this context ( e.g. `(2..-1).each` doesn't match this behaviour).

Comment: If you want to keep the first `n` items, and can alter `arr`, you can use `front = arr.shift(n)`.  A less-desirable alternative to `drop(n)` is `last(arr.size-n)`.

Comment: Note that `Array#[]` is a.k.a `Array#slice`: `ary[2..-1]` can be written `ary.slice(2..-1)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write:

```
ary[2..-1]
# => [3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

`-1` is the index of the last element in the array, see the [doc for `Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) for more informations.

A better alternative in Ruby is to use the [`Array#drop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-drop) method:

```
ary.drop(2)
# => [3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: I used to use the #drop thing, but -1 symbolizing the last element in an array is ultimately the easiest way to remember how to do this and all sorts of other permutations of this sort of thing

Answer (score 15):

Use [Array#drop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-drop)

```
2.1.0 :019 > ary.drop(2)
 => [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: This is the best answer. [It works with all `Enumerable`s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop) and [even lazy enumerators](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-i-drop). To perform the opposite operation, there is the `take(n)` method. Also available are the `drop_while` and `take_while` methods.

Comment: Indeed.. It is best.. :)